# Metric for Bayesian ground truth recovery

Tags: regression, bayesian, model-evaluation, metric

I am developing a new Bayesian model and want to compare it to already existing Bayesian models with the same hyperparameters using a simulation study. I generated 50 datasets and fit 4 different models. Is there an evaluation metric with which I can compare the recovery of the ground truth parameters? Since I am using Bayesian inference, I have a posterior distribution of the parameters.
My current approach is calculating the MAE per trial and model and comparing the distributions over the trials with boxplots:

[image]

The main problem with this is the scale differences between parameters (see left and right). Is there a metric, that does not have the problem with the different scales? $R^2$ does not work, because for each trial I have only one ground truth value, and thus get $R^2=-\infty$

Comment: Why not evaluate the likelihood of your data under your posterior predictive? You could compare this between models. You could also calculate likelihood of the data under prior predictive to understand how strongly your data affected the posterior